# How to pass argument in .desktop file

Tags: linux, .desktop

When launching an application through the command line I successfully use:

```
gourmet --gourmet-directory $HOME/my/custom/path/
```

But it does not work when trying to replicate this behaviour on a .desktop file with:

```
Exec=gourmet --gourmet-directory $HOME/my/custom/path/ %F
```

I am probably missing something very basic here, but I cannot get my head around this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify why you are using `%F` ? should the application open a list of files or it is just an application launcher, then you can open the files from the GUI

Comment: You can make separate script-file with full command like `gourmet --gourmet-directory $HOME/my/custom/path/` than put into `.desktop` full path to the script.

Comment: @lese, good point I actually realised %F was not required. Jodka Lemon's solution worked both with and without it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Only command line options with one hyphen are possible in the Exec field.

`Exec=sh -c "gourmet --gourmet-directory $HOME/my/custom/path/ %F"`

should work.

Comment: Just tried today and `-g=4536+76` and `--geometry=4536+76` both worked equally well as arguments in `.desktop` exec line with or **without** `sh -c` wrapper in Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS Unity Desktop.

Comment: Wrapping command in `sh -c` worked. I wanted to execute this `sudo rogauracore initialize_keyboard; sudo rogauracore black`. I executed it this way -- `Exec=sh -c "sudo rogauracore initialize_keyboard; sudo rogauracore black"`

Comment: Found this answer while searching for a solution to this problem - thanks @Jodka Lemon.  But ... does anyone know *why* this restriction was created?

Comment: It doesn't seems to be true anymore, as the Desktop Specification (https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html) uses "Exec" examples with two hyphens. If it's not working at your distro, consider opening a Bug Report.